# EC2 Metadata credentials to execute API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-requests, boto3

I am using EC2 credentails to authenticate API within AWS environment. EC2 instance has IAM role attached and IAM role has permission to execute APIs.

Below script gets IAM credentails from EC2 metadata and calls API. Somehow auth credentials are not able to execute the call. we are trying to execute this API from

```
import json
import sys
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
import boto3
from ec2_metadata import ec2_metadata


def get_auth_token():
    iam_role=requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/')
    print(iam_role.text)
    
    response = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/'+iam_role.text)
    credentials = response.json()
    print(credentials)
    #print(credentials['AccessKeyId'])
    #print(credentials['SecretAccessKey'])
    #print(credentials['Token'])
    return credentials



output = {}

try:
        '''
        Authenticate API
        @param access_key, secret_key,host, region, service: Token
        '''
        auth = get_auth_token()

        '''
        @sample:
            Execute API
        @param method, url, headers, body, auth: response
        '''
        response = requests.request(method,jsonInput['url'],auth=auth, data=body,headers=headers) #jsonInput['body']
        json_data = response.json().get('status')

        # If *********** API Executed Successfully ****
        if response.status_code == 202 and response.json().get('status') == 'success':
            output['status_code']=response.status_code
            output['status']=response.json().get('status')
            output['message']=response.json().get('message')
            output['headers']=response.headers['Location']
            #print (json.dumps(output))
            
        # If *********** API Execution Unsuccessful ************
        else:
            output['status_code']=response.status_code
            output['status']=response.json().get('status')
            output['message']=response.json().get('message')
            #print (json.dumps(output))

# *********** Exception Caught **********

except requests.exceptions.Timeout as et:
    output['status_code']= 'Timeout'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message']= str(et)
    #print("Timeout: ",et)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as eh:
    output['status_code']='HTTPError'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message'] = str(eh)
    #print("HTTPError: ",eh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    output['status_code']= 'ConnectionError '
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message'] = (str(errc))
    #print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    output['status_code']='GENErr'
    output['status']='failed'
    output['message'] = str(err)

print (json.dumps(output))
```

getting below error

```
   response = requests.request(method,jsonInput['url'],auth=auth, data=body,headers=headers) #jsonInput['body']
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 320, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 551, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: What are you _actually_ wanting to accomplish (that is, _what_ rather than _how_)? It appears that you are wanting to make an API call using AWS credentials, but _what_ are you trying to call? What is the "API within AWS environment" -- is it an AWS service, or is it something running on your own Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: Reading the role from instance metadata happens by default on initialization of boto3. You shouldn't need to do anything manually.

Comment: `boto3.client('someservice')` is all it takes to authenticate and use a service with an IAM instance profile.